# What is the preferred method of migrating from WebSQL to indexedDB?

Tags: indexeddb, web-sql

I have a completed phonegap app that runs on Android currently, the DB is written using WebSQL.

I've been tasked with porting the app to Windows Phone - the app falls apart due to not supporting WebSQL.

Is there a quick conversion/shim script available to stop me having to trawl through my code and change each DB referencing line?

Comment: Answer - no, there isn't. Ended up writing a shim.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`IndexedDB Polyfil`](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/) which wraps WebSQL in IndexedDB.

While this isn't a 100% perfect solution as you'd have to migrate to IndexedDB that would be a better solution in the long run since the WebSQL spec has been discontinued and going forward browsers will move to IndexedDB.

Answer (score 0):

You could try my open source library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/wiki/Home It has limited SQL execution on IndexedDB storage mechanism. Table join is not yet exposed to SQL though.